# Is it possible to embed swf movie in HTML without creating a separate file?

Tags: html, flash, embed

Is there a solution, similar to `img` `data:image/gif;base64...`, that allows to embed an swf movie in a HTML page without having to create a new swf file and link it in the `src` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible in Firefox using the `data` attribute as the embed's `src`: Try it out.

It will definitely not work in Internet Explorer <= 8, because `data:` URIs are allowed only for image data there. Not sure about IE 9, some limits have been lifted in the Beta.

Opera will also fail in most cases, because the maximum size of `data:` URIs is limited to  4 kilobytes there.

I am not aware of a cross-browser way to do this that does not require a separate resource.

[MDC docs on `data:` URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs)

Comment: data URI's do work in IE9, embeded in CSS, local and internet, have used it recently